# Date format should be in cst

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

I have date in our database "2014-03-06 16:23:33". I wanted to display "Mar 06, 2014 04:23:33 pm CST". Using cakephp.

Eg:

```
$this -> Html -> cDate ($courseLog['CourseLog']['completed_time'],'datetimes');
```

Thanks in Adv.

Plz answer ASAP.

Comment: You asked people to _"Plz answer ASAP"_, but 5 days after I posted my answer, you've not accepted, up- or down-voted the answer, nor have you commented to say what, if anything, is wrong with my answer

Answer (score 0):

*Update*
While I initially stated I wasn't sure if CakePHP had a specific helper for this, I'm now almost completely sure they do ***not***.
Their own documentation simply mentions the `DateTime` class, and [link to the PHP docs](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-DateTime.html)
And a github search for anything called `cDate` [shows up empty](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/search?q=cDate&type=Code), `CDATA` is something entirely different anyway...

---

As a follow up to my comment, which I'll delete, but for completeness add here:

I don't know if CakePHP has a specific helper for this, but

```
$date = new DateTime($yourDateString);
$date->format(DATE_RFC820);
```

should be close. [Compose your own format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) according to what you need, or check [the predefined constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types) readily available.

Ok, so the `DATE_RFC850` constant isn't an exact match of the format you are looking for, and string manipulations (as in a series of `substr` and `explode`-`implode` calls) are just tedious and look messy and amateurish. But just *look* at the format parameters!
I suspect you're actually looking for something like this:

```
$date = new DateTime($courseLog['CourseLog']['completed_time']);
$asString = $date->format('M d, Y h:i:s A e');
```

Perhaps it's safer for you to create the `DateTime` instance from the format you know, and expect. You *know* how the string is formatted, so you can use the static method [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), too:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d H:i:s', //yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format
    $courseLog['CourseLog']['completed_time']//the string to parse
);
$asString = $date->format('M d, Y h:i:s A e');
echo $asString, PHP_EOL;
```

As you can see [from this codepad](http://codepad.org/6y9YM4na), this works perfectly...

The format explained:

- `M`: Short textual representation of the month, `F` gives the full month
- `d`: 2 digit (with leading zeroes) representation of the day, change to `j` to drop leading zeroes
- `Y`: 4 digit year, as opposed to `y`, which gives 2 digits
- `h`: 12 hour with leading zeroes, `g` drops the leading zeroes. Capitalize either format and you get the 24 hour version
- `i`: minutes, with leading zeroes
- `s`: seconds, with leading zeroes
- `A`: AM or PM, change to `a` to get *am* or *pm*
- `e`: Time-zone identifier, Alternatives are `T` (timezone abbreviation) or  `O` and `P` (both difference to GMT in hours, `P` adds a colon between hours and minutes (+0400 vs +04:00)

Bottom line, PHP comes with the `DateTime` object which already offers a solid way to work with dates and times, I'd suggest you simply use that *core* object. Whatever CakePHP offers, it'll most likely just be a wrapper around [the `DateTime` and its related classes](http://www.php.net/datetime)